# newsyslog.conf logrotate when file is older than 6 month

Tags: freebsd, backup, syslog, logrotate

I would like to delete following files with newsyslog.conf when the files are older than 6 month:

```
# logfile    [owner:group]    mode    count    size    when    flags    [/pid_file]
/mnt/usb/access_*.log
```

Which other options do I have to set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify values for all of the mandatory fields.

The following will cause new log files to be created with mode 644, and will keep at most 6 files, before deleting the oldest. The `*` in the `size` field tells `newsyslog` not to consider the size of the file when running. `$M1D0` means "rotate the file once a month, on the first day of the month, at midnight". `GJN` tells `newsyslog` that the filename is a shell pattern and that it should rotate all files that match (`G`), that it should compress the rotated file with `bzip2` (`J`), and that it does not need to send a signal to a daemon process (`N`).

```
# logfile    [owner:group]  mode  count  size  when    flags
/mnt/usb/access_*.log       644   6      *     $M1D0   GJN
```

Without knowing more about your use case, it's impossible to give you a more specific instruction. For example, you say nothing about how these files are written, or what ownership should apply, but the `newsyslog.conf` manpage is pretty detailed, and should help you fill in the blanks.

Comment: What is the value for "when", when I want to delete the files each 6 month?

Comment: In this case, 6 in the `count` column will cause `newsyslog` to delete a file once it reaches 6 months of age, based on the fact you are rotating once a month, on the first day of the month, as specified in `when`. `count` controls the number of files to keep, before deleting the oldest to make way for newer ones.